# How to mount a rootfs using NFS to emulate ARM architecture on qemu?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu, nfs, buildroot

I want to emulate ARM architecture on qemu. I followed instructions in this [tutorial](https://devarea.com/building-embedded-linux-system-with-qemu/#.XprniHUzaiv). First I compiled linux-5.5.17 kernel. The only difference between me and this tutorial was the CROSS_COMPILE variable. Mine was arm-linux-gnueabi-. Everything went as the same as this tutorial before building the filesystem.
I used [buildroot-2020.02.1](https://buildroot.org/) to build rootfs. I ran command `make qemu_vexpress_defconfig`. Then I executed `make menuconfig` to set the root password, choose the ext4 root filesystem and set the compression method to "xz". I compiled this rootfs successfully. And I configure NFS following the tutorial above. But when I ran the command

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a15 \
-net tap -net nic -m 512 -kernel /home/myuser/linux-5.5.17/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
-dtb /home/myuser/linux-5.5.17/arch/arm/boot/dts/vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb \
-append "console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/home/myuser/armsystem/outfs ip=192.168.0.2:192.168.0.1:192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:qemu:eth0"
```

Finally I got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtKve.jpg). I don't know whether there are some errors when building rootfs or configuring the network. I searched for some other tutorial to mount NFS rootfs, but it doesn't work for me.I wonder how I can successfully mount a rootfs to emulate ARM architecture on qemu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `,vers=3,tcp` to your nfsroot line, like this: `nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/home/myuser/armsystem/outfs,vers=3,tcp`.

Also the following step is incorrect in the tutorial: `cp -r -d [buildroot]/output/target/* ~/armsystem/outfs`. There's a file THIS_IS_NOT_YOUR_ROOT_FILESYSTEM in the `output/target` directory with an explanation why and what is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the nfsroot line. Then I configured the Buildroot according to the prompt in THIS_IS_NOT_YOUR_ROOT_FILESYSTEM and built the rootfs again. It works for me!